# Sort through a json response in bash

Tags: json, bash

I'm having trouble doing a seemingly trivial task. Say I've got an API response with a following json output:

```
    [
  {
    "id": 47,
    "iid": 12,
    "project_id": 1,
    "status": "pending",
    "soure": "push",
    "ref": "new-pipeline",
    "sha": "a91957a858320c0e17f3a0eca7cfacbff50ea29a",
    "web_url": "https://example.com/foo/bar/pipelines/47",
    "created_at": "2016-08-11T11:28:34.085Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-08-11T11:32:35.169Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 48,
    "iid": 13,
    "project_id": 1,
    "status": "pending",
    "soure": "web",
    "ref": "new-pipeline",
    "sha": "eb94b618fb5865b26e80fdd8ae531b7a63ad851a",
    "web_url": "https://example.com/foo/bar/pipelines/48",
    "created_at": "2016-08-12T10:06:04.561Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-08-12T10:09:56.223Z"
  }
]
```

I want to keep only those objects whose 'created_at' date matches current date. What would be the best way/tools for this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)

```sh
# `printf` can do strftime stuff
today=$(printf '%(%Y-%m-%d)T' -1)   # magic value "-1" is "now"

echo "$response" | jq --arg date "$today" '[.[] | select(.created_at | startswith($date))]'
```

Or, all in `jq`

```sh
echo "$response" | jq '
    (now | strftime("%F")) as $today |
    [.[] | select(.created_at | startswith($today))]
'
```

Comment: I'd maybe use `<<<"$response"` instead of the `echo "$response" |` -- when modern systems use a tmpfs location for TMPDIR that makes creating a heredoc/herestring backing file a bit faster than setting up a pipeline -- but that's a tiny, tiny quibble with a generally excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the JSON parser [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) you could either do a string comparison, checking whether `created_at` starts with the current date as a string:

```
$ xidel -s input.json -e '$json()[starts-with(created_at,"'$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')'")]'
$ xidel -s input.json -e '$json()[starts-with(created_at,substring(current-date(),1,10))]'
$ xidel -s input.json -e '$json()[starts-with(created_at,format-date(current-date(),"[Y]-[M01]-[D01]"))]'
```

Or you could do a logical date comparison:

```
$ xidel -s input.json -e '$json()[date(substring-before(created_at,"T")) eq current-date()]'
```